# Find all sentence permutations with synonymous words?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I've got a two dimensional array of synonyms (or rather, equivalent) words; and a given sentence. I need to return an array of sentences that contain all permutations of words replaced with their synonyms.

Example, given synonyms/equivalences array:

```
const eqs = [
  ['hi', 'hello', 'hey'],
  ['programmer', 'coder']
]
```

And

```
const sentence = 'hello programmer'
```

Return (order is not important):

```
['hello programmer',
 'hi programmer',
 'hey programmer',
 'hello coder',
 'hi coder',
 'hey coder']
```

I'm not able to find *all* possible permutations, only some. Here's what I have +
 [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/namanyayg/pen/KQNWLy?editors=0010)

```
const getAllEquivalentSentences = (sentence, eqs) => {
  const eqSentences = new Set([sentence])
  sentence.split(/\s/).forEach(word => {
    // current is an array of equivalent terms, or array
    // with a single item
    const curr = eqs.find(row => row.includes(word)) || [word]
    curr.forEach(wordEq => {
      if (wordEq !== word) {
        eqSentences.add(sentence.replace(word, wordEq))
      }
    })
  })
  return [...eqSentences]
}
```

Seems like I'll need a dynamic programming solution, but that's getting too complex for me too fast. Is there a simpler approach that I'm missing?

Comment: Does it has the 2d array or probably have multi-dimension array?

Comment: Interesting challenge. Possible recursive solution: https://codepen.io/thbwd/pen/oEYWBX?editors=0011

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys -- @Bergi correctly pointed out that this is a duplicate and I was able to adapt the solution that he linked. It's the cartesian product algorithm and I found an efficient JS solution elsewhere on SO.